# What is the most efficient way of creating new group ids from cross-classified nested groups in SAS?

Tags: sas, sas-macro, proc-sql

I have two tables. The first one has about 370,000 rows with data from college programs between 2010 and 2019. The relevant columns are: `year`,  `program_id`, `college_id`. I kept `program_name` and `college_name` just to make it easier to understand. This is how my data looks:

```
| year | college_id | college_name         | program_id | program_name           |
|------|------------|----------------------|------------|------------------------|
| 2010 | 001        | Wilbor College       | 001        | Civil Engineering      |
| 2010 | 001        | Wilbor College       | 002        | Electrical Engineering |
| 2010 | 001        | Wilbor College       | 003        | Mechanical Engineering |
| 2010 | 001        | Wilbor College       | 021        | English                |
| 2010 | 002        | Mary College         | 031        | Physics                |
| 2010 | 003        | Francis College      | 041        | Arts                   |
| 2019 | 001        | Wilbor College       | 004        | Engineering            |
| 2019 | 101        | South Wilbor College | 022        | English Teaching       |
| 2019 | 101        | South Wilbor College | 023        | English and Spanish    |
| 2019 | 101        | South Wilbor College | 024        | English Literature     |
| 2019 | 223        | Mary&Francis College | 031        | Physics                |
| 2019 | 223        | Mary&Francis College | 032        | Astronomy              |
| 2019 | 223        | Mary&Francis College | 033        | Geophysics             |
| 2019 | 223        | Mary&Francis College | 034        | Biophysics             |
| 2019 | 223        | Mary&Francis College | 041        | Arts                   |
| 2019 | 223        | Mary&Francis College | 042        | Visual Arts            |
| 2019 | 223        | Mary&Francis College | 043        | History of Art         |
| 2019 | 223        | Mary&Francis College | 044        | Cinema                 |
```

The second table has a metadata with about 15,000 rows, with information about linked programs, and two columns `program_id` and `linked_program_id`. This is how it looks:

```
| program_id | linked_program_id |
|------------|-------------------|
| 001        | 002               |
| 004        | 001               |
| 004        | 002               |
| 004        | 003               |
| 021        | 022               |
| 021        | 023               |
| 023        | 021               |
| 023        | 024               |
| 031        | 032               |
| 032        | 031               |
| 033        | 031               |
| 034        | 031               |
| 041        | 042               |
| 041        | 043               |
| 042        | 044               |
```

This second table is important because it allows to identify programs that are linked with each other. There are several types of links, but to put it simple, links are cases in which the value of `program_id` can change over time. Usually these changes happen because there are programs that split or are merged over the years.

This also happens with colleges (splits and merges), but I don`t have the same metadata for colleges. However, it is possible to create it if I can track their programs over the years.

What I want is to add two variables in the first dataset:

1. `group_p_id` : an id that is the same for all `program_id` values that are somehow linked over the years;
2. `group_c_id`: an id that is the same for all `college_id` values that are somehow linked over the years.

The resulting dataset would look something like:

```
| year | col_id | college_name         | prog_id | program_name           | group_p_id | group_c_id |
|------|--------|----------------------|---------|------------------------|------------|------------|
| 2010 | 001    | Wilbor College       | 001     | Civil Engineering      | 004        | 001        |
| 2010 | 001    | Wilbor College       | 002     | Electrical Engineering | 004        | 001        |
| 2010 | 001    | Wilbor College       | 003     | Mechanical Engineering | 004        | 001        |
| 2010 | 001    | Wilbor College       | 021     | English                | 021        | 001        |
| 2010 | 002    | Mary College         | 031     | Physics                | 031        | 223        |
| 2010 | 003    | Francis College      | 041     | Arts                   | 041        | 223        |
| 2019 | 001    | Wilbor College       | 005     | Engineering            | 004        | 001        |
| 2019 | 101    | South Wilbor College | 022     | English Teaching       | 021        | 001        |
| 2019 | 101    | South Wilbor College | 023     | English and Spanish    | 021        | 001        |
| 2019 | 101    | South Wilbor College | 024     | English Literature     | 021        | 001        |
| 2019 | 223    | Mary&Francis College | 031     | Physics                | 031        | 223        |
| 2019 | 223    | Mary&Francis College | 032     | Astronomy              | 031        | 223        |
| 2019 | 223    | Mary&Francis College | 033     | Geophysics             | 031        | 223        |
| 2019 | 223    | Mary&Francis College | 034     | Biophysics             | 031        | 223        |
| 2019 | 223    | Mary&Francis College | 041     | Arts                   | 041        | 223        |
| 2019 | 223    | Mary&Francis College | 042     | Visual Arts            | 041        | 223        |
| 2019 | 223    | Mary&Francis College | 043     | History of Art         | 041        | 223        |
| 2019 | 223    | Mary&Francis College | 044     | Cinema                 | 041        | 223        |
```

Here are the datasets in SAS input format (ids are in numeric format to make transformations easy):

```
data have1;
INPUT year 1-4 college_id 6-8 college_name $10-29 program_id 31-33 program_name $35-56;
datalines;
2010 001 Wilbor College       001 Civil Engineering
2010 001 Wilbor College       002 Electrical Engineering
2010 001 Wilbor College       003 Mechanical Engineering
2010 001 Wilbor College       021 English
2010 002 Mary College         031 Physics
2010 003 Francis College      041 Arts
2019 001 Wilbor College       004 Engineering
2019 101 South Wilbor College 022 English Teaching
2019 101 South Wilbor College 023 English and_Spanish
2019 101 South Wilbor College 024 English Literature
2019 223 Mary&Francis College 031 Physics
2019 223 Mary&Francis College 032 Astronomy
2019 223 Mary&Francis_College 033 Geophysics
2019 223 Mary&Francis College 034 Biophysics
2019 223 Mary&Francis College 041 Arts
2019 223 Mary&Francis College 042 Visual Arts
2019 223 Mary&Francis College 043 History of Art
2019 223 Mary&Francis College 044 Cinema
;
run;

data have2;
INPUT program_id 1-3 linked_program_id 5-7;
datalines;
001 002
004 001
004 002
004 003
021 022
021 023
023 021
023 024
031 032
032 031
033 031
034 031
041 042
041 043
042 044
;
run;

data want;
INPUT year 1-4 college_id 6-8 college_name $10-29 program_id 31-33 program_name $35-56 broad_c_id 58-60 broad_c_id 62-64;
datalines;
2010 001 Wilbor College       001 Civil Engineering      004 001
2010 001 Wilbor College       002 Electrical Engineering 004 001
2010 001 Wilbor College       003 Mechanical Engineering 004 001
2010 001 Wilbor College       021 English                021 001
2010 002 Mary College         031 Physics                031 223
2010 003 Francis College      041 Arts                   041 223
2019 001 Wilbor College       005 Engineering            004 001
2019 101 South Wilbor College 022 English Teaching       021 001
2019 101 South Wilbor College 023 English and Spanish    021 001
2019 101 South Wilbor College 024 English Literature     021 001
2019 223 Mary&Francis College 031 Physics                031 223
2019 223 Mary&Francis College 032 Astronomy              031 223
2019 223 Mary&Francis College 033 Geophysics             031 223
2019 223 Mary&Francis College 034 Biophysics             031 223
2019 223 Mary&Francis College 041 Arts                   041 223
2019 223 Mary&Francis College 042 Visual Arts            041 223
2019 223 Mary&Francis College 043 History of Art         041 223
2019 223 Mary&Francis College 044 Cinema                 041 223
;
run;
```

The tricky thing is that the second table (the metadata) is not very well organized. Some ids appear in both in columns `program_id` and `linked_program_id` in a "many-to-many" way.

I tried to solve this problem myself, but the code is getting very complicated, and I am not so sure anymore if I am doing the right thing. So here is what I did:

1. Make sure that every id is listed in both columns (both as `program_id` and `linked_program_id`):

```
proc sql;
create table temp_1 as
select distinct
program_id,
linked_program_id
from have2
union
select distinct
linked_program_id as program_id,
program_id as linked_program_id
from have2;
quit;
```

2. Compute the maximum of program_id by linked_program_id, vice-versa, and then the maximum of each row:

```
proc sql;
create table temp_2 as 
select
max(ID_0, ID_1) as ID_2,
*
from (select 
   max(linked_program_id) as ID_1, 
   *                 
   from (select 
        max(program_id) as ID_0, 
        *
        from temp_1
        group by linked_program_id) 
    group by program_id);
quit;
```

3. The last step attributed the same new id for most of linked programs, but not to all of them. Therefore, I repeated the same logic of last step 3 times in a macro (taking the new id `id_2` as it first input):

(Running the loop once was enough for the sample dataset that I provided here. But in my 15,000 rows dataset, I had to run it 3 times until I got the same id for all linked programs. )

```
%macro max_rep;
proc sql;
%do i=3 %to 9 %by 3; 
create table temp_%eval(&i.+2) as 
select
max(ID_&i., ID_%eval(&i.+1)) as ID_%eval(&i.+2),
program_id, linked_program_id
from (select 
    max(ID_&i.) as ID_%eval(&i.+1),
    *
    from (select 
        max(ID_%eval(&i.-1)) as ID_&i.,
        *
        from temp_%eval(&i.-1)
        group by linked_program_id) 
    group by program_id);

drop table temp_%eval(&i.-1);

%end;
quit;
%mend;
%max_rep;
```

4. Finally, I run a join between the `have1` and `temp_11`:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select
t1.*,
t2.ID_11 as group_p_id
from have1 as t1 
left join (select distinct ID_11, program_id from temp_11) as t2
on t1.program_id=t2.program_id;
quit;
```

This gave me half of what I wanted. Now I have a unique id for each program that belong to the same group of linked programs. I did some additional changes conditional on other variables to get the broader program of each linked group as my `group_p_id` (instead of just the max value). Then I realized that I still need to figure out how to create a new group id for colleges (`group_c_id`). There must be an easier and more efficient way of doing this is SAS, isn't there?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is very similar in nature to code sample for "How to group people by their first name OR last name" at https://www.devenezia.com/downloads/sas/samples/#hash8.  The general proposition is "Given: P = p{i} = (p{i,1),p{i,2}), a set of pairs (key1, key2).

    Find: The distinct groups, G = g{x}, of P,
          such that each pair p in a group g has this property:

          key1 matches key1 of any other pair in g.
          -or-
          key2 matches key2 of any other pair in g."

Comment: Thank you very much, @Richard , I am going to take a look at it!